# How can I cross-compile TVM for RISC-V on x86 Ubuntu 22.04.2 using LLVM and GCC toolchain?

Tags: gcc, llvm, riscv, tvm, apache-tvm

How to cross compile TVM to RISCV on x86 Ubuntu 22.04.2?

I want to cross-compile TVM for RISC-V on x86 Ubuntu 22.04.2.

Environment:

TVM version: 0.13.0-dev0

LLVM : sudo apt install llvm, version: 14.0.0

GNU toolchain for RISC-V : sudo apt-get install gcc-riscv64-linux-gnu, version: 11.3.0

I turned off the "use_libbacktrace" option in the config.cmake file and disabled the "USE_ALTERNATIVE_LINKER" option in the CMakeLists.txt file.

TVM cross-compile for RISC-V

```
cmake .. \
    -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Linux \
    -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=1 \
    -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/riscv64-linux-gnu-gcc \
    -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/riscv64-linux-gnu-g++ \
    -DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=/usr/riscv64-linux-gnu \
    -DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM=NEVER \
    -DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY=ONLY \
    -DMACHINE_NAME=riscv64-linux-gnu

make -j$(nproc)
```

Then I encountered the following error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/riscv64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../riscv64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/libLLVM-14.so: error adding symbols: file in wrong format
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/tvm.dir/build.make:1448: libtvm.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:253: CMakeFiles/tvm.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2
```

Thanks!

Comment: You also need to build llvm for riscv